# Generate google play gift card code automatically

Tags: android

I'm developing an app with its own currency (users can earn point).
They have the ability to redeem it as cash, donate it, or buy a Google Play gift card.

Is there a way to automate the process of getting a Google Play gift card code? Is there an API for that?
The process phases:

1. User requests to redeem points as google gift card
2. My server get this request and generates a gift card code
3. Gift card code is sent back to the user mail

Comment: How could your server "generate a gift card code"? You have to pay for it

Comment: *Is there an API for that?* Note that explicitly asking for an off site resource is off topic.

Comment: An off-site resource, sure, but asking how to do something with the official API isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible through third-party APIs, such as [NGC](https://www.giftcardapi.com/google-play), but they require a certain amount of order volume - contact them to make sure your use case falls within their abilities.